# Converting longtext to datetime for use in wordpress (MySQL database)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, datetime

I am working on a wordpress website and I need to get some sort of calendar working, where I get the upcoming event to show in the sidebar. To do this, I added a meta field (date) to the custom post type. What I would like to do, is fetch the upcoming event through sql (MySQL).

I know you can compare datetimes to certain functions (such as CUR_DATE() and NOW()), but the problem is that, due to my data being stored as a metafield, it has the longtext type and not the datetime type, making it impossible to compare and select my data to the mentioned functionalities. I tried using CONVERT, but this throws a syntax error. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Below you can find the sql that is throwing the syntax error. If I leave out the statement with CONVERT in it, I get results. My dates are formatted as d-m-Y btw.

```
SELECT p.ID FROM tt_posts p
INNER JOIN tt_postmeta pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id

WHERE 
    p.post_type = "activity" AND
    p.post_status = "publish" AND
    pm.meta_key = "date" AND
    CONVERT(DATETIME, pm.meta_value) >= NOW()

ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC
```

Comment: Try using CONVERT(<fieldname>,DATETIME) AS <newfieldname>. Then use the new field to use it with NOW().

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me. I placed the convert in between my JOIN and my WHERE statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your longtext date should be a unix timestamp and wordpress is a php application, so just do:

```
$timestamp = 1465731381;
$dateObject = date('d.m.Y h:i:s', $timestamp);
```

this would give you a date object formatted like:

```
12.06.2016 11:36:21
```

refer to [php manual - date](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) for more formatting options.

Afaik mysql also has the function to convert any date object (like `date.now()`) to a unix timestamp: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

more info: [mysql manual - date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is kind of what I was trying to avoid, because I wanted the date stored like that in the database. I did go ahead and store my data differently, left out the 'convert' and it works just fine. I am going to leave the question open for now though, because I would like to know if there are any solutions where I can use my current formatting to compare to NOW(). I will accept your answer if nobody else replies though :)